# Riemann integral of a non continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

We have a function $f : I=[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

a) Show that for every partition V of I, we have that $\underline{S}(f,V)=0$
b) Show that $$\overline{\int}_0^1 f(x)dx =1$$

For me the difficulty with this questions is that it feels so logical but I don't know how I can really show or if I may use it that every interval on $[0,1]$ contains both rational and irrational numbers. If I some how would know/show this property I feel I can easily solve this problem. So my question is, would I have to proof this intiutive idea about intervals on $[0,1]$ for a course on analysis or is this a know result (or even "worse" is it not even true?0

Comment: For this sort of problem, it's probably safe to assume that the rationals and irrationals are both dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I haven't used dense before, so I don't see how that would help me with this problem, could you perhaps explain a little more?

Comment: @RubenMeijs: "Dense" _means_ that every open interval contains an element of the set in question.

Comment: In my textbook they use the following definition: D is dense in V if every point of V is a limitpoint of D. I didn't directly see what this would give me the needed property. But I think I get it now, because if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limitpoint of $\mathbb{Q}$, then every interval containing $x$ also contains rational (and thus also irrational) numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a fact that every nontrivial interval $(a,b)$ contains both rational and irrational numbers.

It is overwhelmingly likely that you can get away with assuming this as background knowledge.

If you do need to prove it, you need to go back to your precise assumptions and axioms about what the real numbers *are*. In most cases it will come down to *Archimedes' axiom* telling you that there is some natural number $N$ that is larger than $1/(b-a)$; the interval will then contain at least one rational with denominator $N$.

Once you have a rational $q\in(a,b)$, either $\frac{q+b}2$ or $q+\frac{b-q}{\sqrt2}$ will be an irrational between $q$ and $b$.

Comment: So if it's a fact then I can probably just used it for this course. But I will try to prove it, with the hints you gave I should be able to do it. Thanks!